# makefile.am variable to set some libs after object files in make command

Tags: makefile

I have a some code that use the clang libs. I want to use a makefile.am and the autotools to compile it. My problem is that in the compile command, my clang libs must be after the objects files for example:

```
 clang++ $(CXXFLAGS) -o myprog myprog.o -lclanglibs1 -lclanglibs2
```

When I create my makefile.am I have used:

```
 myprog_LDFLAGS = -lclanglibs1 -lclanglibs2
```

which in fact result in the Makefile:

```
 clang++ $(CXXFLAGS) -lclanglibs1 -lclanglibs2 -o myprog myprog.o
```

And this don't compile (this is a particularity of the clang libs, if I generate manualy the compile command clang++ $(CXXFLAGS) -o myprog myprog.o -lclanglibs1 -lclanglibs2, it works)

I have tryed to skirt this problem with the use of the variable myprogram_LDADD but I get an error because the autotools detects that I it contains some linking libs and autotools says to use myprog_LDFLAGS.

How can I set the clang libs in such manner that they will appear at the end of the compile command?

edit :
in my makefile.am I get some clang libs like this:

```
 -lclanglibs1 -lclanglibs2 $(shell llvm-config --libs)
```

Comment: Do you get an error or a warning? You can ignore it if it is a warning since it is merely a suggestion, not a requirement. The documentation states "'PROG_LDADD' is inappropriate for passing program-specific linker flags (**except for '-l', '-L', '-dlopen' and '-dlreopen'**)." According to that, you can use myprog_LDADD instead of myprog_LDFLAGS in this case.

Comment: Yes I have an error message which is linker flags such as '--libs)' belong in 'myprog_LDFLAGS' I have updated the description of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

the problem is how is done the substitution by make with the shell command.
this variable :

```
 myprog_LDADD = $(shell llvm-config --libs)
```

is not expanded by the autotools and configure, myprog_LDADD is expanded by make which check the content and display an error.

I have to get the libs from configure.ac like this:

```
AC_SUBST([LLVMLIBSLD],[$(llvm-config --libs )])
```

and then add the variable in myprog_LDADD.

```
 myprog_LDADD=@LLVMLIBSLD@
```